# .net Web API password Encryption methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have developed a .net sample application using the tutorial given in

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

In this sample application when register new user with username and password, the password is encrypted and stored in DB table. I need to know which encryption method is used as default.

Can I configure this to use any other encryption methods instead of default provided?

For Ex: if default encryption method is SHA256 how to configure it to use SHA512?

Comment: SHA256 and SHA512 are not encryption algorithms, nor are they suitable for password storage.

Comment: @Luke Park ,That is just to clarify what i'm asking, can you tell me which encryption method is used and how it is configured.

Comment: How do you encrypt (hash?) the password? Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: i didn't do any custom code, just developed application following the  tutorial given in

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api